# Whose 1930 number theory result is used in characterizing perfect 2-error correcting linear codes?

Tags: mathematics, reference-request, number-theory, 20th-century, ramanujan

In *Error-Correcting Codes: A Mathematical Introduction* (Chapman & Hall, 1998), John Baylis wrote (p.109)

> Moving on to 2-error correcting linear codes, the condition for perfection of linear codes of dimension $k$ is
> $$M = 2^k = \frac{2^n}{1 + n + \binom{n}{2}} = \frac{2^{n+1}}{2 + n + n^2}$$
> so $2+n+n^2$ must be a power of 2.  It was shown in 1930 that $n = 1, 2, 5$ and 90 are the only positive integers for which this is true.

without any citation.  Any ideas whose 1930 number theory result he had in mind?  Of course, a reference would be wonderful.

This came up in a MathOverflow [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412940/when-do-binomial-coefficients-sum-to-a-power-of-2/413024#413024) about when $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{N}{n}$ is a power of 2.

---

Edit: As markvs explains in his answer (and as discussed in my answer to the MO question), this is equivalent to what is now known as the Ramanujan--Nagell equation $2^n + 7 = x^2$.  This only deepens the question of what Baylis was referring to:

- Is there a 1930 result that addresses $2^n + 7 = x^2$, predating Nagell's 1948 solution (and Ljunggren's 1943 posing of the problem, both presumably unaware of Ramanujan's 1913 question)?
- Was there a 1930 result about when $n^2 + n + 2$ is a power of 2 with no connection made to Ramanujan's question?

Comment: Who is the first (so far) known person to state and prove that $n^2 + n + 2$ or the sum of the first three numbers in a row of Pascal's triangle (as Golay put it in 1949) can be a power of two iff $n=1,2,5,90$?  Nagell does not seem to do it. Was it Cohen 1964?

Comment: @Conifold  There are two possibilities the Cohen mentions.  (1) Shapiro & Slotnick come very close (On the mathematical theory of error correcting codes, IBM Journal, 1959): they invoke an additional condition from coding theory for one case of their Theorem 5 since "the calculation is reduced somewhat," but they claim it could be done without it.  (continued in next comment)

Comment: @Conifold (2) Browkin & Schinzel (Sur les nombres de Mersenne qui sont triangulaires, C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris, 1956) find all solutions to $2^x - 1 = y(y+1)/2$, which is closer than the form of Ramanujan's question.  By the way, based on the title of a 1960 work of the same two authors, On the equation $2^n−D=y^2$ (Bull. Acad. Polon. Sci. Sér. Sci. Math. Astronom. Phys.), they probably made the connection to the Ramanujan-Nagell equation, although I have not been able to access this latter article to verify their references.

Comment: At least, the MR reviewer (S. Chowla) of their 1960 paper did make the connection in MR0130215, according to MathSciNet.

Answer (score 4):

See [this oeis entry](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C5%2C90&language=english&go=Search). This can be easily reduced to [Ramanujan-Nagell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Nagell_equation) problem. It was conjectured by Ramanujan in 1913 and resolved by Nagell in 1948 (where the year 1930 come from is not clear).

Comment: Thanks.  I'll add this background to the question; I had found these connections in the MO question.  Perhaps Baylis was referring to an earlier solution of Ramanujan's "conjecture," or something more directly in the context he mentioned.

Comment: The solution of R. conjecture was in 1948. The fact that it implies your statement was noticed in the 21st century ($\sim$ 2012). I am not sure adding an answer to a question is appropriate, but do as you wish.

Comment: The connection between Nagell's solution and the statement about binomial sums was made by 1964 at the latest: Edward Cohen, A note on perfect double error-correcting codes on $q$ symbols, Information and Control 7 (1964) 381-384.

Comment: What I wrote is taken from OEIS. Ask them to correct the error. Anyway Nagell's solution is dated 1944, not 1930. 1964 is also not 1930.

Comment: Thus the original question;

Comment: The most reasonable explanation of 1930 is that it is a misprint.